# React App Docker image copy is taking too long

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16 as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json /app/

ARG PROJECT_NAME=react-ui

RUN npm install --force 
COPY ./ /app/
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm -rf ./*

COPY --from=build-stage /app/build/ .

EXPOSE 8080 

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Step --> COPY ./ /app/ is taking too long, currently almost 50 mins and running. How do I fix this?

I tried building without the below step and it takes 4 mins average

```
RUN npm run build
```

but what I understand is we need to include npm run build too, right? This is my first time dockerizing a React Frontend App. Your help would be really appreciated, thank you

Comment: What is the `docker build` command you're running?  What directory are you running it in, and what's in that directory besides your front-end application?  Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I rarely use this site to post my own questions so it's a bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is copying node_modules folder as well, although I have included that in .dockerignore. So my solution to this was to specify directly which folder and contents I need to copy rather than copying everything using COPY ./ /app/